# Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but Users has 1'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm using Firestore with SwiftUI and I try to make a simple query to get documents from a sub-collection:

```
struct MyCardsView: View {
    
    @State var myCards = [MyCard]()
    
    @State var show: Bool = false
    @State var selectedId: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            List(self.myCards){i in
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    self.selectedId = i.card_id
                    self.show.toggle()
                    
                    
                }) {
                    
                    MyCardCell(cardId: i.card_id)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                db.collection("Users").document(uid).collection("Fiches").order(by: "date", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
                    
                    guard let documents = snap?.documents else {
                        print("No documents")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    self.myCards = documents.compactMap({ (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> MyCard? in
                        return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: MyCard.self)
                    })
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$show){
            CardsView(cardId: self.selectedId)
        }
        
    }
}
```

This view has always worked, but since yesterday I get the following very strange error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but Users has 1'

I really don't understand because the path is correct and the sub-collection exists...

Comment: What is the specific value of `uid` here?  Note that if you do a web search for this error message, you will come up with a LOT of results.  As I look at this question on Stack Overflow, it's showing me lots of the same question in the "related" section.

Comment: Yes I know, I tried evrything but nothing works...

Comment: The uid is correct and even when I try with a hardcoded value, It does not work

Comment: If you've hard coded everything, I suspect the error doesn't have anything to do with this code.

Comment: So where is the error coming from?

Comment: It seems unlikely that the error comes from `db.collection("Users").document(uid).collection("Fiches")`, as it has at least two segments in there already. You should be able to find the source line when you right click on the red indicator of the error message and click "Reveal in Issue Navigator". \

Comment: @Kolya do find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Im having this same issue, but only in my canvas previews. The app runs fine. I've looked through my code and have figured it to come down to this block of code, because theres only one reference to the collection and not to a document ID, however on the Firebase documentation, it says that this code is good even though it only has one segment. (although I'm just taking a guess)

```
public func fetchAllArtists(completion: @escaping ([Artist]) -> Void) {
    var _artists: [Artist] = []
    database
        .collection(ContainerNames.artists)
        .getDocuments { snapshot, error in\
            guard error == nil else { return }
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                // do stuff
            completion(_artists)
        }
}
```